# How to color only 25% bottom of a circle?

Tags: html, css

How do I totally color the bottom (only 25%) of a circle using CSS?

I want something like this:

Sample needed:
[image: Sample needed]

Result I have for now:
screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

I want to remove the gap in the bottom and padding left and right

```css
.story svg {
  fill:none;
  stroke:red(218, 218, 218);
  stroke-width:4px;
  stroke-dasharray:1;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke:#ff008c;
}

.semi-circle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 30%;
  width: 71%;
  border-radius:  0 0  100% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(219, 219, 39),  red);
}
```

```html
<a class="" rel="">
  <i style="border-radius: 16px"></i>
  <svg class="" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40">
  </svg>
  <div class="semi-circle"> <span class="sm-text"> Video </span>  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way on how you can do it

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle .box {
  background-color: #9F3F40;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="box">
    <h2>video</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is i am working with svg and i want the semi circle inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved it.

I tried doing it on my own and it kind of worked. Just try this and see if it works.

HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
  <span class="text">text</span>
  <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px gray;
  margin: 50px
}

.fill {
  background-color: teal;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 80px;
  z-index: 1000;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

I think it's proper and you can change the color as you need. I will be giving the screenshot of the circle as well. Take a look at this:

[image: Circle]

Comment: the problem is i am working with svg and i want the semi circle inside it.

Comment: I doubt you can do it with a SVG. This is the best way possible.

Comment: my svg is running an animation when i try to fill it, it stops the animation that's why i wanted to draw a shape like a half circle and place it in the bottom

Answer (score 1):

I would use overflow: hidden on a parent div and flexbox to align the text with background to the bottom.

```css
.circle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d4d4d4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
 
 }
 
.circle p {
 color: white;
 background: darkred;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 24px;
 margin:0
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <p>video</p>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is i am working with svg and i want the semi circle inside it.